# Self help question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, close-reasons

The question "[What exactly is neuroplasticity, and can it be demonstrated with a simple experiment?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30863/what-exactly-is-neuroplasticity-and-can-it-be-demonstrated-with-a-simple-experi)" was closed because of off-topicness due to self-help. The only reference to a do-it-yourself was one of the sub-questions whether plasticity could be tested at home. The title was a bit unfortunate as it disregarded the core of the question, namely *what is neuroplasticity*. I removed the self-help and I hope for it to be re-opened. Please note my edits were started after the first few close-votes were in, and have continued after closure. So, please (re-)assess the edits and the question.

The thing is that there have been other questions with way more far-reaching implications posed as do-it-yourself home-based experimental questions. Notably the well-received question [How to obtain bacteria samples at home?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/how-to-obtain-bacteria-samples-at-home) that talks about "cool pathogenic bacteria" and the extensively answered and upvoted [Is it possible to genetically modify a plant at home?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19873/is-it-possible-to-genetically-modify-a-plant-at-home) and [Are there ways to speed up the growth of plants?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/are-there-ways-to-speed-up-the-growth-of-plants) and the list continues.

Why was this question put on hold, as there was only a mention of "Can I test brain plasticity at home?" Answer: No. There you go. The other questions above were way more targeted at irresponsible home-baked experiments and were not only allowed, they were heavily upvoted and elaborately answered.

Comment: Have you asked the people who voted to close why made such a decision?

Comment: @dustin,  that is what I tried doing here. Probably not the most effective  way :)